# AJAX not working with ASP.NET HTTP Handler

Tags: asp.net, jquery, httphandler

I'm doing something stupid, I suppose.  I swear I've done this before without issues but right now I can't get it to work.  I have an HTTP handler written in ASP.NET that I want to invoke via AJAX (using jQuery).  In my web.config, I register the handler like this...

```
 <httpHandlers>
     <add verb="GET" path="~/getPage.axd" type="Handlers.GetPage"/>
 </httpHandlers>
```

The handler is just setup to test right now...

```
Namespace Handlers

Public Class GetPage
    Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext) Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        With context.Response
            .Clear()
            .Write("ID: " & context.Request.QueryString("id"))
            .End()
        End With
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
End Namespace
```

And I have the following jQuery to invoke it...

```
$.get('http://localhost:81/getPage.axd?id=0', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

I know the URL used to make the request is correct.  IIS is setup to route the axd path to the ASP.NET ISAPI filter. I have verified that my handler is *not* getting invoked (I changed handler to print log message and nothing was printed.  Event viewer shows nothing).

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
When I try to navigate directly to the handler in the browser, I get a 404 error.

Comment: What do you get when you browse to the handler directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  I had my path wrong in web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET" path="getPage.axd" type="Handlers.GetPage"/>
</httpHandlers>
```